# What exactly is min_samples_leaf in scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, hyperparameter

I'm confused about a particular part of the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier). I want to know what `min_samples_leaf` refers to when it's input as a float.

> **min_samples_leaf** : int or float, default=1
> The minimum number of samples required to be at a leaf node. A split point at any depth will only be considered if it leaves at least min_samples_leaf training samples in each of the left and right branches. This may have the effect of smoothing the model, especially in regression.
> If int, then consider min_samples_leaf as the minimum number.
> If float, then min_samples_leaf is a fraction and ceil(min_samples_leaf * ***n_samples***) are the minimum number of samples for each node.

My question is this: `n_samples` is not a valid parameter of this model. If I set `min_samples_leaf` to 0.1, does that mean that at least 10% of the `max_samples` (i.e., the total number of samples taken during the bootstrap) have to be in each child, or does it mean that at least 10% of the samples *that are currently in that node being considered for splitting* must be in each child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n_samples` is an implicit parameter of the model when calling fit and predict functions, calculated based on `X` or `y` matrices, e.g.

```
X: {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
```

So, when float, `min_samples_leaf` is the percentage of the total number of samples during training; not the number of samples in the node that is to be split.

This can also be seen in the following code segment of [decision tree](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e517759b4696c74ecc35c6e2eb508cff/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L281) classifier:

```
...
# Determine output settings
n_samples, self.n_features_in_ = X.shape
...
min_samples_split = int(ceil(self.min_samples_split * n_samples))
...
```

Comment: Thanks @gunes! I appreciate the clarification.